# Earliest browsers that support if-modified-since or if-none-match headers

Tags: http, browsers, http-headers, cross-browser, compatibility

Based on my observations, google and probably many others are in love with websites that include the Etag and Last-modified headers along with the if-modified-since and if-none-match header checking because they contribute to higher speed browsing, however, back in the day, headers in use were namely Expires and Cache-control.

I read elsewhere that google chrome browser ignores cache-control sent by the server and uses a value of zero. Because of this, I'm going to stick with using Etag and Last-Modified headers.

My question is what are the first browsers and versions that support Etag, Last-modified, If-modified-since and If-none-match headers?

The reason why I ask is because my site for the most part is a site that displays photos but I don't want people with extremely old computers to throw them out and buy new ones just in order to view a set of pictures. I would rather build a very large set of happy guests instead.

Comment: Are you asking for which browsers first supported the headers individually, or together?  Because if-modified-since has been around a *long* time.  I remember back in the mid-1990s having all sorts of headaches the first time we had daylight saving in the Netscape 0.9x days, before there was 'force reload' (which told the client to *not* send an if-modified-since header).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read elsewhere that google chrome browser ignores cache-control sent by the server and uses a value of zero.

Citation please? The only reference I found of this is a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245767/is-chrome-ignoring-control-cache-max-age) (June 2012) that states that Chrome will override `Cache-Control` if the user specifically refreshes the page - which is understandable.

This would also be strange since [Google recommends `Cache-Control` headers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en#cache-control) in its developer guidelines. `Cache-Control` is the "newer standard" (although still quite *old*) and should take priority over other headers if present.

> what are the first browsers and versions that support Etag, Last-modified, If-modified-since and If-none-match headers?

With regards to `ETag` / `If-None_match`, [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247761/browser-support-for-etags) (June 2011) states:

> all browsers in popular use, IE5.5+, Safari, Chrome, Opera, and Firefox, all support the ETag/If-None-Match headers.

...but it will no doubt predate this list. (ETags were part of the original HTTP/1.1 spec formerly introduced in 1997.)

`Last-modified` / `If-Modified-Since` will certainly predate `ETag`s. I would think the very early browsers would have supported these. This represents the basic fundamentals of any caching mechanism.